# NSTabView not working in NSAppearanceNamedVibrantDark Popover

Tags: cocoa, nstabview

When I try to put an NSTabView inside a vibrant dark Popover (as an NSPopover contentViewController's view) I get a completely black background. When I put it in a regular vibrant dark window, it works. When I put it in a vibrant light popover or window it also works.

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see, the controls inside "go through" the black background and show the vibrancy.

Comment: Have you tried telling the view to draw background, not draw background to see if it makes any difference? What happens if you set the background colour to clearColor?

Comment: Checking/Unchecking that setting doesn't make a difference. How would I change the background color? Subclassing?

Comment: Just make sure the tab view is not drawing it's background. Normally there is an option for that in xcode. Otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass of `NSTabView` and override `allowsVibrancy` will fix it:

```
override var allowsVibrancy: Bool {
    return true
}
```